# SQL performance subquery in field vs join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to know which query's performance will be better by using subquery in the field or join.

For example i have two tables book & author (with one to many relationship between them as Author 1->* Book).

```
Sub Query in field (fetching author name using subquery):
select 
 b.book_id,
 b.book_name,
 b.author_id,
 (select author_name from author where author.id=b.author_id as author_name
 from book b

Join Query (fetching author name by joining book & author tables):
select 
 b.book_id,
 b.book_name,
 b.author_id,
 a.author_name
 from book b inner join author a on b.author_id = a.author_id
```

I am using Postgres DB and if i check query plan then join is doing nested loop, whereas subquery just using PK author_id. I have index on author_id column.

Answer (score 0):

These do different things.  The equivalent of the first query is a *left* join, not an *inner* join.  And then they are only equivalent if you can guarantee that `author` never has more than one match.

In addition, the first will return an error if `author` returns more than one row for a given `author_id`.

So, you should use the version that does what you want.

That said, if you have two equivalent versions of the query (using a `left join`), then then execution plans should be pretty similar.  In particular, both will take advantage of an index on `authors(author_id)` -- which is what you really care about from a performance perspective.